# Any API changes with confidential mode?

Tags: gmail-api

Will 'confidential' messages/threads automatically be prevented from getting returned in API search results, or are there any code changes we need to make to prevent apps from breaking?

When new features like this get added to Gmail, it would be nice if the API release notes were simultaneously updated with an explanation of how the changes will impact the API. E.g. 2+ years later, there is still no explanation of whether or not gmailified inboxes can be accessed via the API.

Just trying the API to see what gets returned isn't useful, because then it's not clear whether or not you're building on an officially supported feature or just an undocumented implementation that's subject to change without warning.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there's not much info about changes in Gmail API with the coming of new features like *confidential mode*. But, you can stay updated with the [official Gmail Blog](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/04/introducing-new-gmail.html) about this.